# Chrome does not repeat animation inside of HTML "details" element

Tags: html, css

I want to animation elements under the `summary` of a HTML `details` element. On Firefox everything works ok and the animation is repeated whenever I open/close the `details` element. But on Chrome the animation is only ran on the first open and never again.

```css
details {
  font-size: x-large;
}

details[open] ul li {
  animation: expand-details 1s ease-in-out;
}

details[open] ul li:nth-child(1) {
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
}
details[open] ul li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
}
details[open] ul li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}

@keyframes expand-details {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -20px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Click me to open an animated list of items</summary>
  <ul>
    <li>These elements</li>
    <li>should ease in</li>
    <li>with a duration of 1s.</li>
  </ul>
</details>
```

What do I need to do to restart the animation in Chrome when I close and open the `details` element?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using Javascript.

```js
function detailsToggled(e)
{
  if (e.srcElement.open) return;

  const copy = document.createElement("details");
  copy.innerHTML = e.srcElement.innerHTML;
  copy.addEventListener('toggle', detailsToggled);

  e.srcElement.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, e.srcElement);
}
// Add the event listener to all details elements on the page
document.querySelectorAll('details').forEach(d => d.addEventListener('toggle', detailsToggled));
```

```css
details {
  font-size: x-large;
}

details[open] ul li {
  animation: expand-details 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes expand-details {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -20px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Test</summary>
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</details>
```